# Laptop shutting down abruptly

Tags: 20.04, shutdown, laptop

I am using ubuntu 20.04, recently I am having the issues of abrupt shutdown when I wont use the laptop for a while. After searching I found this in var/log file

```
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:03:14 vasi kernel: [28139.722294] amdgpu: [powerplay] can't get the mac of 5
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:03:15 vasi systemd[1446]: Reached target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:03:15 vasi systemd[1446]: Stopped target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:03:15 vasi systemd[1446]: Started Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:03:21 vasi kernel: [28145.962890] amdgpu: [powerplay] VI should always have 2 performance levels
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:03:24 vasi systemd[1446]: Reached target Shutdown.
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:04 vasi boltd[8632]: power: state located at: /run/boltd/power
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:04 vasi boltd[8632]: power: force power support: yes
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:04 vasi boltd[8632]: power: setting force_power to ON
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:04 vasi boltd[8632]: power: state changed: supported/on
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:04 vasi boltd[8632]: power: guard '1' for 'boltd' active
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:07 vasi geoclue[7870]: Service not used for 60 seconds. Shutting down..
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:09 vasi boltd[8632]: manager: acquired power guard '1'
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:09 vasi boltd[8632]: power: guard '1' for 'boltd' deactivated
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:09 vasi boltd[8632]: power: shutdown scheduled (T-20.00s)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:09 vasi boltd[8632]: power: state changed: supported/wait
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:09 vasi boltd[8632]: power: state changed: supported/on
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:09 vasi boltd[8632]: power: guard '2' for 'fwupd' active
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:29 vasi boltd[8632]: power: got event for guard '2' (10)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:29 vasi boltd[8632]: power: guard '2' for 'fwupd' deactivated
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:29 vasi boltd[8632]: power: shutdown scheduled (T-20.00s)
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:29 vasi boltd[8632]: power: state changed: supported/wait
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:49 vasi boltd[8632]: power: setting force_power to OFF
/var/log/syslog:Sep 15 14:04:49 vasi boltd[8632]: power: state changed: supported/off
```

Somewhere It says shutdown scheduled. Is it normal? Or any app is misbehaving or something. Guide me.

```
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: at-spi-dbus-bus.service: Succeeded.
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: gnome-session-manager@gnome-login.service: Succeeded.
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Stopped GNOME Session Manager (session: gnome-login).
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Stopped target Tasks to be run before GNOME Session starts.
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Stopped target Session services which should run early before the graphical session is brought up.
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Reached target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Stopping Start gnome-keyring as SSH agent...
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Starting Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown...
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Stopped target Shutdown running GNOME Session.
Sep 16 10:35:09 vasi systemd[1276]: Started Restart DBus after GNOME Session shutdown.
Sep 16 10:34:53 vasi systemd[2286]: gnome-session-failed.target: Requested dependency OnFailure=gnome-session-shutdown.target ignored (target units cannot fail).
```

EDIT
No output for `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`

```
ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Aug 20 06:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 15 11:42 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Apr 23 13:05 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 28 20:09 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

[image]

```
free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       1.4Gi        27Gi       251Mi       2.0Gi        29Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi        59Mi       1.9Gi
```

Comment: Do you have any thunderbolt accessories attached?

Comment: @heynnema Yeah I have a usb hub attached(USB 3.0) . But I'm sure I don't have an thunderbolt port. This laptop is a 5 year old one.

Comment: Disconnect the USB hub, and USB accessories and see if the problem is better.

Comment: I saw a similar issue and there accepted answer as to uninstall bolt. Should I follow that?. Because my laptop is connected to a external monitor and USB hub is the key. I cannot disconnect always and reconnect when I am using.

Comment: Give me the link for that answer so I can take a look. Try the USB suggestion from my previous comment first.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519043/sudden-shutdowns-on-ubuntu-18-04-acer-laptop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113043/discussion-between-adupa-vasista-and-heynnema).

Comment: @heynnema even after uninstalling bolt and removing the USB hub, still the shutdown happened. An extra log has been attached, have a look

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and a full-screen screenshot of `top`. Have you installed any "power-saving" or "battery-saving" or "laptop performance" utilities?

Comment: @heynnema Yes Once I installed this TLP, but again I uninstalled it.

Comment: Log into a different account (create one if need be) and see if the shutdowns happen there too.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: Your `TOP` command doesn't show mem/swap values. Show me `free -h`.

Comment: @heynnema Post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From comments and chat...

We determined that the laptop battery is defective. On AC power, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of testing with the software, finally concluded that my battery is the root cause. Should have done hardware test initially :(

Comment: Isn't this answer the same as the accepted answer? Also the problem now appears to be "I unplugged my TV and it stopped working" or "My car ran out of gas and stopped running".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix We initially ruled out the possibility of battery damage due to the weird things in syslog. This is a laptop, not a desktop to stop working when unplugged.

Comment: If question title was "Laptop shuts down when running on battery and left alone" it changes everything.